# How can I check that a string contains a certion word actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I check that a string contains a certion word actionscript?

Answer (score 4):

The [indexOf](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#indexOf%28%29) method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for the existence of a word in strict sense (as a whole word, not part of another word), you can use regular expressions. For example, the string `"hat"` is contained in the string `"I like that movie"` as a substring but not as whole word. Use the [`String::match(pattern:*)`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#match%28%29) method to search for regular expressions in a string.

```
var str:String = "I like that movie";
var t1:RegExp = /hat/;     // `/` is the delimiter
var t2:String = /\bhat\b/; // `\b` denotes word boundary
if(str.match(t1) != null)
  trace("hat is a substring");
if(str.match(t2) == null)
  trace("but hat is not present as whole word");
```

Comment: Just a note, RegExp::test(string:String) will return a Boolean, thus removing the comparison with null. Ex.: if(t1.test(str)){...}